# Set Value of checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to uncheck a checkbox if an adjacent cell has a value input in it.

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var eventRange = event.range;
  if (eventRange.getColumn() == 3) { // 3 == column C
    var columnFRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventRange.getRow(), 6, eventRange.getNumRows(), 6);
    var values = columnFRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
       values[i][0] = 'FALSE';
    }
    columnFRange.setValues(values);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks at a sheet called "Testing" and if there is a value in column A it will put "TRUE" in the adjacent cell to the right.  I believe this is what you're going for?

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testing");
  var hasValue = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

  var value = '';


  for(var i = 0; i < hasValue.length; i++){



    if(hasValue[i][0].length > 0) {

    sheet.getRange("B" + (i + 1)).setValue("TRUE");
    }
    else {
    sheet.getRange("B" + (i + 1)).setValue("");
    }

  }

}
```